# Facebook Post Insights for personal feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to fetch `/me/feeds` or `/me/posts` while getting some insights like impressions or reach?

For example, this query will at least give me likes and shares:
`/me/posts?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true),shares`

What's missing is something like impressions.

The Graph API Explorer shows me an `insights` field, but that doesn't seem to work. I found this query that actually executes, but returns no additonal field or info: `/me/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_fan,post_engaged_users)`

My goal is to read the personal posts of a user and provide him insights about his reach (like common analysis tools do for Pages). For that, I'd need a handy way to fetch posts along with their insights. If that won't be possible, it's still acceptable to get insights from specific personal posts.

Thank you for any help / advice

Comment: It doesn't exist

Comment: @WizKid thank you for your comment. Are you sure that it's impossible to get any valuable insights from such a post except likes, shares and comments?

Comment: Yes I am. But if you don't trust me you can read the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs